# How to copy a directory from one hard drive to another with every single file?

Tags: command-line, directory, cp

I have a folder I just luckily recovered sitting on:

```
/media/sdc1/Pictures
```

with a BUNCH of subdirectories and files that I need.

I want to copy these to a folder on:

```
/media/sdb1/Pictures
```

What command do I have to use in the terminal to make sure this happens?  I know there is the `cp` command. But is that the best choice? And if so what options should I use to ensure I get every single directory and file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would use rsync for this so that if there is an error (or you need to stop copying) partway through you can easily resume later, without having to recopy everything.

```
rsync -av /media/sdc1/Pictures/ /media/sdb1/Pictures/
```

Comment: I'd remove the `*` since it will omit dotfiles at the first level. It may also cause it to exceed the ARG_MAX limit.

Comment: @geirha good point. edited.

Comment: And to resume I need to use the same command again?

Comment: Yes, rerunning the command will reassess what’s changed and resume the transfer, effectively picking up where it left off previously

Answer (score 12):

`cp -r /media/sdc1/Pictures/* /media/sdb1/Pictures/some_dir`

- The `-r` is recursive, <sup>read the [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cp)...</sup>
- With `/media/sdc1/Pictures/*` the asterisk is to copy all the contents of `/media/sdc1/Pictures/`, but not the parent directory itself.
- The some_dir of `/media/sdb1/Pictures/some_dir` is where you want to put it.

Comment: will this copy dotfiles and dotdirs as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you need an exact image, use the command `dd if=(path) of=(path)`

Comment: Beware, this command could completely kill you computer if used incorrectly

Comment: You can't copy directories with `dd`!

Comment: WARNING:  I don't have enough rep to downvote but this command is not suitable for copying directories, and in the worst case can trash your system.